# Update multiple variables in switch-case in C# 9.0

Tags: c#-9.0

I am trying to do a switch-case statement and update several variables and can't figure out how to do that using the new switch-case syntax in `C# 9.0`.

This is a kind of what I am trying to do:

```
public static void MyMethod(string value)
{
    string a, b;

    a = value switch
    {
        nameof(value1) => "result1",
        nameof(value2) => "result2",
        _ => "default"
    };
}
```

I would like to update also "b" variable, I know I can use the old syntax and maybe this is the right way, is there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, using [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples):

```
var (a, b) = value switch
{
    "value1" => ("a1","b1"),
    "value2" => ("a2","b2"),
    _ => ("default a","default b")
};
```